# How to name a Parent component when it's children have nothing in common?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I've a Form component like the following:

```
<Form>
  <Image .. />
  <X .. />
</Form>
```

`X` is a component which consists of regular HTML elements an input, a drop-down and a button.
My question is how do you come up with a name for component `X` when it's children clearly have nothing in common?

A name that anybody can understand without going through the code to figure out what is this component. What is your thought process?

Also, I can't break the `X` component down to smaller separate components as I need them together as a one component to create multiples of it on demand.

Comment: This is quite an opinion based question. IMO name it according to the overall function it performs. You could call it `Controls`.

Comment: FormSection, FormPart

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle But some can come up with very descriptive names and others can't, That's why I'm asking for their thought process. Also why `Controls`? I mean it doesn't describe the component it is still vague. The component consists of a text input, a drop-down and a button.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz That's a generic name and it doesn't describe the component either, Why did you choose that name?

Comment: @RogueScarlet Stay focused on naming the components.